# How does Flask appear to be skipping print statements

Tags: python, flask, plotly-dash

I have a Dash application that lets the user filter a pandas dataframe, which results in a graph. They can also download a CSV of the filtered dataframe. This is accomplished by passing arguments to the URL, retrieving the arguments using `flask.request.args`, refiltering the database, and writing the output to a file.

While working on this solution, I added print statements to help me track variable values. Although the download link is working with the desired result, I came across some behavior that I don't fully understand. I think this may have something to do with `@app.server.route` and when/how it is executed.

For example:

1. `Print` statements are not *always* executed. They are executed sometimes.
2. They seem to have a higher rate of execution once I apply filters, rather than clicking the download link with no filters applied.
3. After applying a filter, clicking the download link, and confirming that it caused the `print` statements to execute, reloading the app and applying the same filter *may* result in the `print` statements **not executing**.

The download link always performs as intended, but I do not understand how the dataframe is being filtered and written via `@app.server.route('/download_csv')`, while also skipping over the `print` statements.

**UPDATE**

I have produced an MRE for Jupyter notebooks. Please note that you must `pip install jupyter-dash` for this code to execute.

Some notes:

1. I ran three tests where I would click the download CSV link 10x each.
2. In the first two tests, the print statements executed 8/10 times.
3. In the final test, they executed 3/10 times.
4. In the third test, I cleared the age dropdown and performed most of the tests with it as 'Null.' *Sometimes* print statements will execute and return 'Null', however most times there was no execution.

The MRE is below:

**Update 2**

After waiting 24hrs and running the code again, all of the lines in `@app.server.route` **seem** to be executing. That is, until I click the download button quickly after changing filters. When this happens, I can get the `print` statements to **not** execute. Despite not executing, the other lines are. Some guesses as to what is going on:

1. When the `print` statements don't execute, it seems that a previous version of the code is being executed. Perhaps it is stored in some temporary memory location?
2. It seems that restarting the system or long periods of inactivity cause the current version of the code to become the default when `print` statements don't execute.
3. `print` statements seem to execute less frequently after quick filter changes and download requests.

```
import plotly.express as px
from jupyter_dash import JupyterDash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import numpy as np
# Load Data
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':np.arange(100), 'name':['cat', 'dog', 'mouse', 'bird', 'rabbit']*20, 'age':np.random.randint(1,30,size=100)})
# Build App
app = JupyterDash(__name__)
app.layout = html.Div([
    html.H1("JupyterDash Demo"),
    dcc.Graph(id='graph'),
    html.Label([
        "names",
        dcc.Dropdown(
            id='names', clearable=False,
            value='cat', options=[
                {'label': names, 'value': names}
                for names in df.name.unique()
            ])
    ]),
    
        html.Label([
        "age",
        dcc.Dropdown(
            id='age', clearable=True,
             options=[
                {'label': att, 'value': att}
                for att in df.age.unique()
            ])
    ]),
    html.Br(),
    html.A(
        "Download CSV",
        id="download_csv",
        href="#",
        className="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm"
    )
])
# Define callback to update graph
@app.callback(
    [Output('graph', 'figure'),
    Output('download_csv', 'href')],
    [Input("names", "value"),
     Input('age', 'value')]
)
def update_figure(names, age):
    
    if not names:
        names = 'Null'
        fil_df = df
    else: 
        fil_df = df[df['name'].isin([names])]
        fig = px.bar(
            fil_df, x='id', y='age',
            title="Animals"
        )
    
    if not age:
        age = 'Null'
        fil_df = fil_df
    else:
        fil_df =  fil_df[(fil_df['age'].isin([age]))]
        fig = px.bar(
        fil_df, x='id', y='age', title="Animals"
        )
        
        
    return fig, "/download_csv?value={}/{}".format(names, age)
   



    
app.run_server(mode='inline')

@app.server.route('/download_csv')
def download_csv():
    value = flask.request.args.get('value')
    value = value.split('/')
    
    selected_1 = value[0]
    selected_2 = value[1]
    
    print(selected_1)
    print(selected_2)
    
    str_io = io.StringIO()
    df.to_csv(str_io)

    mem = io.BytesIO()
    mem.write(str_io.getvalue().encode('utf-8'))
    mem.seek(0)
    str_io.close()
    return flask.send_file(mem,
                           mimetype='text/csv',
                           attachment_filename='downloadFile.csv',
                           as_attachment=True)
```

Comment: I think you'll need to create a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this. I don't see anything obviously wrong here.

Comment: I thought that might be the case. I will work on it. Thx

Comment: Might want to append some extra text to your print statements to make sure selected_1 and selected_2 have values. Something like:
print("Selected_1: ",selected_1)
This way you would print something even if those variables are empty.

Comment: @alif I appended text as per your suggestion and ran. The print statements are still being 'skipped' *sometimes*

Comment: @coralvanda The MRE produces the same inexplicable behavior as the original code.

Comment: I ran it, but it doesn't ever seem to execute the `download_csv` func for me, nor the `print` statements.

Comment: This is strange If the goal is to logg these values maybe try flask logging to see log those values? Also are you running flask in debug mode?
https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/logging/

Comment: @coralvanda Are you clicking on the download CSV link that appears? That is the trigger.

Comment: @alif The goal is not to log the values. I only added the print statements to test whether the proceeding and subsequent lines were being executed. In the original code, the subsequent lines write the selected filters to the `StringIO object` before writing the CSV as a way of tracking which filters were applied in the output file. I wanted to 'test' which lines were being executed because clicking the download link would result in a filtered CSV, but *sometimes* the filters wouldn't be written to the file, and *sometimes* they would be.

Comment: I saw the button to download, but it didn't appear that anything was happening when I clicked it.